# dyld: Library not loaded (ConnectionKit)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode6, connectionkit

Well, yes, you guessed it right: the usual usual issue with libraries not found.

The weird thing in this particular situation is that the exact same project compiles and runs fine using my non-MAS build settings, but fails at launch with my MAS settings.

Here's the complete error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ConnectionKit.framework/Versions/A/ConnectionKit
  Referenced from: /Users/drkameleon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTestApp-emticmktwwdxvpfyewalbxctwglm/Build/Products/AppStore (Debug)/MyTestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyTestApp
  Reason: image not found
```

What's going? Where should I look? (`@rpath` and framework linking has never been my strongest point, and I'm really lost...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work.

**Build Settings** > **Linking** > **Other Linker Flags**

```
-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../Frameworks
```